# How to returns fixed length array in solidity

Tags: remix, contract-debugging, memory

I get the following error, how to resolve it?

```
Expected type name function Array_Data () public view returns (memory uint []) {^ ---- ^.
```

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.6.0;

contract Lock {
    uint[] public _gas_left;
    
    function closeAccount() public {
        _gas_left.push(gasleft());
    }
    
    function Array_Data() public view returns(memory uint[]) {
        uint[] memory arrayOfgas = new uint[](20);
        for (uint i = 0; i < _gas_left.length; i++)
            arrayOfgas[i] = _gas_left[i];
        return arrayOfgas;
    }
}
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should resolve your error.

It should be `returns(uint[] memory)` not `returns(memory unit[])`

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.6.0;

contract Lock {
    uint[] public _gas_left;
    
    function closeAccount() public {
        _gas_left.push((gasleft()));
    }
    
    function Array_Data() public view returns(uint[] memory){
        uint[] memory arrayOfgas = new uint[](20);
        for (uint i = 0; i < _gas_left.length; i++)
            arrayOfgas[i] = _gas_left[i];
        return arrayOfgas;
    }
}
```